# Why does iterator type deduction fail?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, type-deduction

Why does this not work in C++?
Why can't I restrict `foo`'s parameter to `std::vector<T>::iterator` like this, and what is the best workaround?

```
#include <vector>

template<class T>
void foo(typename std::vector<T>::iterator) { }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    foo(v.end());
}
```

The error is:

```
In function ‘int main()’:
     error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(std::vector<int>::iterator)’
     note: candidate is:
    note: template<class T> void foo(typename std::vector<T>::iterator)
    note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
     note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’
```

Comment: The workaround is the usual one when a template parameter can't be deduced, give it explicitly: `foo<int>(v.end());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main reason it doesn't work is because the sandard says that
the `T` here is in a non-deduced context.  The reason why the
context is not deduced is because when you pass some type to the
function, the compiler would have to instantiate every single
possible `std::vector` (including for types not present in this
particular translation unit) in order to try to find one which
had a corresponding type.

Of course, in case of `std::vector`, the compiler could contain
some magic to make this work, since the semantics of the class
are defined by the standard.  But generally, 
`TemplateClass<T>::NestedType` can be a typedef to literally
anything, and there's nothing the compiler can do about it.

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

```
struct X {};
template<> class std::vector<X> {
    typedef std::vector<int>::iterator iterator;
};
```

Oops.

Templates are Turing-Complete. You are asking the compiler to infer the arguments from the results. This is impossible in the general case, even ignoring the possibility of non-one-to-one correspondence.

Typically, you take the iterator type itself as template parameter. This permits other random-access iterators like deque, circular buffer, etc.