# c++ template specialization, error when using typename

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I need to specialized a member function:

```
template <typename T>
int32_t writeVectorVariableUnit(
    foo& classFoo,
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator& start,
    typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator& stop,
    const std::string& name,
    const std::string& unit,
    const std::string& longName,
    const std::vector<std::string>& dimName) const
```

in this way:

```
template <>
int32_t writeVectorVariableUnit(
    foo& classFoo,
    std::vector<uint16_t>::const_iterator& start,
    std::vector<uint16_t>::const_iterator& stop,
    const std::string& name,
    const std::string& unit,
    const std::string& longName,
    const std::vector<std::string>& dimName) const;
```

but the g++ compiler (version 4.4.7 on a redhat 6.7) complains that is not able to match any template declaration:

> error: template-id ‘writeVectorVariableUnit<>’ for ‘int32_t
>   writeVectorVariableUnit(foo&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >&, const std::string&, const std::string&, const std::string&,
>   const std::vector,
>   std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >&) const’ does not
>   match any template declaration

I suspect that is related with the usage of typename, I try several combination without success. 
Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issues have nothing to do with the usage of `typename`, they are

1. You should specialize the template out of the class definition.
2. For `std::vector<uint16_t>::const_iterator`, `T` can't be deduced as `uint16_t` because this belongs to [non-deduced contexts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts). That means you have to specify the specialized template parameter explicitly.

> If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is
>   not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> 1) The nested-name-specifier (everything to the left of the scope
>   resolution operator ::) of a type that was specified using a
>   qualified-id:

e.g.

```
template <>
int32_t bar::writeVectorVariableUnit<uint16_t> (
//      ~~~~~                       ~~~~~~~~~~
    foo& classFoo,
    std::vector<uint16_t>::const_iterator& start,
    std::vector<uint16_t>::const_iterator& stop,
    const std::string& name,
    const std::string& unit,
    const std::string& longName,
    const std::vector<std::string>& dimName) const {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive T here is actually in a non deduced context, so the function cannot actually deduce T ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208628/why-does-iterator-type-deduction-fail))

worst case you could do:

```
writeVectorVariableUnit<float>
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f03f4bc1d96ef07)